# Why do i keep getting 'Instance of shared preferences' when trying to store string?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store the username of the user, but when I print the username it says 'Instance of SharedPreferences'. I'm not sure what isn't working

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as _text_ rather then an image

Comment: I agree, give code not photos of it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create an `instance` of `shared preferences` whenever you want to store a new variable.

Like in your 1st image, you are creating the instance of `shared preferences` 3 times.

you can set all these values using a `single instance`

```
var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await sharedPreferences.setString("userId",userId);
await sharedPreferences.setString("username",username);
await sharedPreferences.setString("email",email);
```

And if you want to get the value of any stored value from `shared preferences` you can get it like this.

```
var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username");
print(username);
```

Like this, you can get the stored String from the `shared Preferences`

And setString is an asynchronous operation so use `async` in it.
and getString is a synchronous operation so no need to use `async` in it.

Happy Coding :)